# Multiple if statements for forms

Tags: jquery, validation

My current statement:

```
if (recaptcha == '' || name == '' || email == '' || emailCheck || emailVerify || priority == 'pap' || topic == 'pat' || message == 'message') {
    $('#incorrmsg').html("Please fill in the fields").slideDown("slow");
} else { 
    //else statemnt goes here
}​
```

The problem with this is that it can only do this with one id.

I want to change it to this statement:

```
if (name == '') {
    $('#incorrname').html("Please fill in your name").slideDown("slow");
}

if (email == '' || emailCheck || emailVerify) {
    $('#incorremail').html("Please fill in and verify your email").slideDown("slow");
}

if (priority == 'pap') {
    $('#incorrpri').html("Please pick a priority").slideDown("slow");
}

if (topic == 'pat') {
    $('#incorrtop').html("Please pick a topic").slideDown("slow");
}

if (message == 'message') {
    $('#incorrmess').html("Please type in your message").slideDown("slow");
} else {
    //else statemnt goes here
}​
```

I want to show all the messages at the same time if there is an error in the fields.
That means I don't want to use the `else if` statements.

So what do I do?

Comment: The code that you have appears to do what you are aksing for. Did you try it?

Comment: As `Guffa` said, the code shown seems to do this. If it doesn't would you be able to throw together a small fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net showing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're giving yourself more trouble than you need to with the specificity. Use an array, push all of the errors onto it in your validation process, then display the errors in your output process.

```
var err = new Array();
if(email == '' || emailCheck) {
  err[] = 'Yo, your email is messed up.';
}

if(err.length > 0) {
  for (var i=0;i<err.length;i++)
    { 
      $('#errors').append('<li>' + err[i] + '</li>');
    }
}
```

Additionally, you might look into the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). It was very helpful when I started learning, both for ease of implementation and for understanding how to best structure JavaScript functions.

Comment: Ya, I'm a noob. I dont want to ue the validation plugin because it already does the stuff for you. I want to learn :D and thanks.

Comment: Learning is good. One of the most important things that you can learn is to not try and reinvent the wheel, and take the opportunity to use and read through tools provided by other people as learning opportunities.